Nuxt 3 Authentication with Supabase using Google OAuth only
I've implemented sign-in with google oauth with supabase. It works, it can sign-in user in to the app but I don't know how to capture the data from user like profile picture, name and email from the provider (Google) to store in supabase database and retrieve it to display on my website. Help!
Here's my code in Auth page
<script setup lang="ts">
const alert = () => {
  window.alert("Redirecting...!");
};


const user = useSupabaseUser();
const { auth } = useSupabaseClient();

const redirectTo = `${useRuntimeConfig().public.baseUrl}/confirm`;

watchEffect(() => {
  if (user.value) {
    navigateTo("/home");
  }
});
</script>
<template>                        
<button
                          class="btn btn-outline-success"
                          type="button"
                          @click="
                            auth.signInWithOAuth({
                              provider: 'google',
                              options: { redirectTo },
                            })
                          "
                        >
                          <Icon name="logos:google-icon" /> Sign in/up with
                          Google`your text`
                        </button>
</template>


If the user signs up using OAuth, the user's info like the avatar URL and stuff will be saved in the meta data of the users table. https://github.com/supabase/auth-js/issues/670
